# Jasmine maven plugin parsing test result Atlassian Bamboo

Tags: maven, junit, jasmine, bamboo, jasmine-maven-plugin

So I've managed to get jasmine maven plugin to work with maven and our js unit test.

All is running well, but i found when there's a test that failed, bamboo will say it failed, but the error is "No failed tests found, possible compilation error ocurred".

I've tried to get it to parse TEST-jasmine.xml result by specifically specify the folder JUnit parser needed, and get jasmine to write to that folder using jasmineTargetDir tag in pom.xml, but it's still not finding the right result. Jasmine faithfully write the test result to the folder, but seemingly JUnit is not parsing it?

Any clue as to why and how to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Running on Bamboo v 5.14.3.1 I've configured the Maven task of Default Stage to search for test result files:

[image: maven step configuration]

And then produced fake failing test. After that the build failed with failing test:

[image]

Hope this helps